# Showing category totals in a table with a repeat control

Tags: xpages

I have a view with two categories.

First category is branch name, which I select from a combobox and store in a viewScope variable.

Second one is year, which should be my table's row header. 
There are 12 other columns every one resembling a month of year.

This is my view and red rectangle is the result I want to replicate in a table.

[image: s]

This is my current progress on repeat control's data source. But I don't know exactly how to use this on computed fields.

```
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase("","erpx/report7.nsf", false);

var v = db.getView("(xpChartCostByProjectYear)");

var nav:NotesViewNavigator = v.createViewNavFromCategory(viewScope.project);
var entry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getFirst();
var vAccnt = db.getView("(chartCostByProject)");
var values = []; // create an empty array
while (entry!=null && !entry.isTotal()){
var obj={};
var year =[];
getComponent("computedField3").setValue(nav.getCount())

year.push(entry.getColumnValues().get(1));
obj.year = entry.getColumnValues().get(1);

obj.jan = entry.getColumnValues().get(2);
obj.feb =entry.getColumnValues().get(3);
obj.mar =entry.getColumnValues().get(4);
obj.apr=entry.getColumnValues().get(5);
obj.may=entry.getColumnValues().get(6);
obj.jun=entry.getColumnValues().get(7);
obj.jul=entry.getColumnValues().get(8);
obj.aug=entry.getColumnValues().get(9);
obj.sep=entry.getColumnValues().get(10);
obj.oct=entry.getColumnValues().get(11);
obj.nov=entry.getColumnValues().get(12);
obj.dec=entry.getColumnValues().get(13);
values.push(obj);


var tmpentry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getNextCategory();
entry.recycle();
entry = tmpentry;}

return values;

}]]></xp:this.value>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to simplify your code before you bind it to anything. How about:

```
    var db = session.getDatabase("","erpx/report7.nsf", false);
    var v = db.getView("(xpChartCostByProjectYear)");
    var nav:NotesViewNavigator = v.createViewNavFromCategory(viewScope.project);
    var dataLabels = ["dummy","year","jan","feb ","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"]
    var entry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getFirst();
    var vAccnt = db.getView("(chartCostByProject)");
    var results = []; // create an empty array
    while (entry!=null && !entry.isTotal()){
        var obj={};
        var curVals = entry.getColumnValues();
        for (var i=1; i<14; i++) {
            obj[dataLabels[i]] = curVals.get(i);
        }

        results.push(obj);
        var tmpentry:NotesViewEntry = nav.getNextCategory();
        entry.recycle();
        entry = tmpentry;
    }
    //Cleanup
    nav.recycle();
    vAccnt.recycle();
    db.recycle();
    return results;
```

The data source needs a variable name e.g. `curRow`. Then you bind your field to curRow.jan curRow.feb etc.

I would try to avoid side effects like the one where you push the value to computedField3. If you need something like that, you might be better off with an object data source.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
        xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

        <xp:this.data>
            <xe:objectData var="objectData" readonly="true" scope="view">
                <xe:this.createObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:return new com.notessensei.ViewWithTotals("dbName","ViewName")}]]></xe:this.createObject>
            </xe:objectData>
        </xp:this.data>
        <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="curRow"
            value="#{javascript:objectData.getRowData(session,viewScope.projectName);}">
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{curRow.jan}"></xp:text>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2" value="#{curRow.feb}"></xp:text>
        </xp:repeat>
    </xp:view>
```

Then you need a class `com.notessensei.ViewWithTotals` that can house your result values and even cache them if you don't expect them to change while you view the page.

The class could look roughly like this:

```
    package com.notessensei;

    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Stack;
    import java.util.Vector;

    import lotus.domino.Database;
    import lotus.domino.NotesException;
    import lotus.domino.Session;
    import lotus.domino.View;
    import lotus.domino.ViewEntry;
    import lotus.domino.ViewNavigator;

    public class ViewWithTotals {

        private final String dataLabels[] = {"dummy","year","jan","feb ","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"};
        private final String dbName;
        private final String viewName;
        private final Map<String,Collection<Map<String,String>>> viewValues = new HashMap<String, Collection<Map<String,String>>>();
        private int totals = 42;

        public ViewWithTotals(String dbName, String viewName) {
            this.dbName = dbName;
            this.viewName = viewName;
        }

        public Collection<Map<String,String>> getRowData(Session session, String catName) {
            if (!this.viewValues.containsKey(catName)) {
                this.populateViewValues(session, catName);
            }       
            return this.viewValues.get(catName);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        private void populateViewValues(Session session, String catName) {
            try {
                Database db = session.getDatabase(null, this.dbName);
                View v = db.getView(this.viewName);
                ViewNavigator nav = v.createViewNavFromCategory(catName);
                ViewEntry ve = nav.getFirst();
                Collection<Map<String,String>> result = new Stack<Map<String,String>>();
                while (ve != null) {
                    ViewEntry nextVe = nav.getNextSibling(ve);
                    Map<String, String> oneEntry = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Vector val = ve.getColumnValues();              
                    for (int i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
                        oneEntry.put(this.dataLabels[i], val.get(i).toString());
                    }
                    result.add(oneEntry);
                    ve.recycle();
                    ve = nextVe;
                }

                this.viewValues.put(catName, result);

                nav.recycle();
                v.recycle();
                db.recycle();
            } catch (NotesException e) {
                // TODO Fix this
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Exercise left to the reader...
        public int getTotals() {
            return this.totals;
        }
    }
```

While this is a little more work, it should give you a) better performance (you could have a refresh() method to clear the stored values) and b) you can add additional values you can use to bind to other fields (like the totals here). It provides the best flexibility.

One experience: use dependency injection (as in: provide the session as parameter), so you can test the class outside XPages too (Unit tests!).

Hope that helps.
**Note**: Typed the code off my head. Can contain typos and syntax problems

Comment: wow... it's a lot to take in, but very helpful. First snipped solved my problem. computedvalue3 thing was just a test for me. But this class will work wonders for my future projects. Thank you!